# How can I solve this coding problem efficiently which involves the 'modulo' operation?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, modulo

We are given an integer 'N' . We can choose any 2 numbers (a and b) in the range (1 to z) . The value of L is given by,

```
L = Max(( (N%a) %b) %N)
```

We have to calculate the number of pairs (a,b) which give(s) the value 'L' . 
I know the brute-force , one, O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution. 
Is there any more efficient way to solve this problem?!

Comment: Whats the meaning of the `Max` in the formula? There is only one argument to it.

Comment: Discovering that there is no efficient solution is surely the point of the assignment.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: What is `z`? Did you mean `N`? If so the outer `%N` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can decipher `Max(( (N%a) %b) %N)` is that the max is taken over all `a, b` pairs. If I am wrong, please disregard the rest.

In case `z > N/2`:

- First, observe that if both `a` and `b` are greater than `N`, then `(N%a) % b` yields `N`, so `(N%a) %b) %N` yields 1, which is unsatisfactory small. Therefore at least one of them shall be less than `N`.
- Second, observe (better yet, prove) that the maximal value of `N % a` is achieved when `a` is `N/2 + 1` for even `N`, and `(N + 1)/2` for odd (*important note*: it is a half of the next multiple of 2 after `N`). Call it a `maximizer`.
- Finally, observe that any `b` greater than that modulo leaves it untouched. Prove that this is indeed the desired maximum.

Now you have enough facts to come up with effectively a one-line program (don't forget the `a > N, b = maximizer` case).

The same logic works for `z < N/2`. Finding the maximizer is a bit trickier, but still possible in `O(1)` (see the *important note* above).

Comment: Thanks. I already solved it and saw your comment now, yup n/2 is the trick here, but if z<n/2 , then things get very complicated cuz the maximizer can't be found in O(1) , luckily in my question, z>=N , so things went pretty easy.